# PHPExcel: Unable to use cache during write

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

I have some memory issues when writing xls (xlsx) files with PhpExcel. I have tried to use the cache but it does not seem to work when writing new documents.

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize'  => '8MB'
                  );
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
```

After an library update to current version (v1.8.1) the problem have improved a bit but still I am able to prepare and export only a file with 8 columns and 15000 - 20000 rows (20000 rows with `cache_in_memory_gzip`) without increasing the memory limit. Unfortunately in my case this is not sufficient solution.

Cache method can maybe allow me to prepare more entries ahead but during the actual write method nothing seems to matter.

```
    $file = new PHPExcel();
    // Prepare data ...
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($file, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save($pathname); // More memory required
```

Comment: Are you enabling caching ___before___ instantiating the new PHPExcel object?

Comment: And don't forget that caching isn't a magic bullet that eliminates memory restrictions completely; even with caching, there's still some memory overhead, and different caching options will vary in reducing that overhead

Comment: I am setting cache as soon as possible. Cache method  can maybe allow me to prepare more entries ahead but during the actual write method  nothing  seems to matter.

For testing purposes I do not use data from database and I am using some pre-set dummy data and for loop. When tested with data from database I have got mostly same results (note that I test with 5000 rows steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end we have switch to [box/spout](https://github.com/box/spout).
I can not claim that I have tested its full capabilities but I have got bored after 800 000 rows.

Comment: Box/spout may currently (**2016-08-04**) 'lack' some styling and export options. However in this case the memory footprint and number of rows where crucial.